# Android onResume crash

Tags: android, sms, runnable

I made an app that reads specific type sms using runnable. Everyhing works fine. I recieve the sms , move it from unread state to read one , but it crashes onResume() and give following error:

```
Unable to resume activity {com.android.testthread/com.android.testthread.MainActivity}: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
```

**How to solve this problem ??**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    boolean recieved = false;
    private TextView text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!recieved) {
                    doFakeWork();
                    text.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            List<Sms> list = getAllSms();

                            if (list.size() > 0) {
                                if (list.get(0).getAddress().equals("Engage") && list.get(0).getFolderName().equals("inbox") && list.get(0).getReadState().equals("0")) {
                                    setReadMessage(list.get(0).getId());
                                    text.setText("Got it");
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, list.get(0).getMsg(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    recieved = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();

    }

    public void setReadMessage(String SmsMessageId){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("read",true);
        getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),values,
                "_id="+SmsMessageId, null);
    }

    public List<Sms> getAllSms() {
        List<Sms> lstSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
        Sms objSms = new Sms();
        Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();

        Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
        this.startManagingCursor(c);
        int totalSMS = c.getCount();

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {

                objSms = new Sms();
                objSms.setId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
                objSms.setAddress(c.getString(c
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
                objSms.setMsg(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
                objSms.setReadState(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("read")));
                objSms.setTime(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")));
                if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).contains("1")) {
                    objSms.setFolderName("inbox");
                } else {
                    objSms.setFolderName("sent");
                }

                lstSms.add(objSms);
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        c.close();

        return lstSms;
    }

    private void doFakeWork() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access cursor which already closed.
1) Try to close that cursor in onDestroy and onPause this is the right way.
2) And try to open it in onResume.